# How does loggerpro generate its uncertainty in position and time when conducting motion analysis at a given FPS and scale (e.g. metre ruler)?

Tags: error-analysis, software, experimental-technology

I am conducting a physics experiment where I am trying to find the terminal velocity of a falling coffee filter by recording the drop on my phone at 4K 60 FPS and using the video to create a position vs time graph, allowing me to calculate the terminal velocity by finding the slope of the linear portion. However, even without entering the uncertainties for position and time in the columns, logger pro generated an uncertainty on the slope of the graph. I, then, entered the uncertainty for the position as 0.005m and uncertainty for the time as 1/60s, yet the uncertainty of the slope didn't change. Therefore, I was wondering how Loggerpro even came up with the uncertainty in terminal velocity without me giving it any information apart from that the video was taken at 60 FPS.

Comment: LoggerPro probably did a least squares regression and based its uncertainty on that.  However, you would have to contact the LoggerPro manufacturer, and hope that they would divulge possibly proprietary information to get an exact answer.